# Swift 2 - Loading data from an array into cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an array `var previousSongs = [PreviousSong]()`.

This array is populated with information in a function called `getSongs()`. I know that the information is being put correctly into the `previousSongs` array

I want to use the information in this array in a table.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(4,0,0,0);
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    previousSongs = [PreviousSong(song: "NAME1", artist: "ARTIST1", time: "TIME1"), PreviousSong(song: "NAME2", artist: "ARTIST2", time: "TIME2"), PreviousSong(song: "NAME3", artist: "ARTIST3", time: "TIME3"), PreviousSong(song: "NAME4", artist: "ARTIST4", time: "TIME4"), PreviousSong(song: "NAME5", artist: "ARTIST5", time: "TIME5"), PreviousSong(song: "NAME6", artist: "ARTIST6", time: "TIME6"), PreviousSong(song: "NAME7", artist: "ARTIST7", time: "TIME7"), PreviousSong(song: "NAME8", artist: "ARTIST8", time: "TIME8"), PreviousSong(song: "NAME9", artist: "ARTIST9", time: "TIME9"), PreviousSong(song: "NAME10", artist: "ARTIST10", time: "TIME10"), ]
    getSongs()
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

func getSongs() {

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://api.vicradio.org/songs/history?amount=10")!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) in

        if error != nil {
            return
        }

        let name = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
        var songName = ""
        var artistName = ""
        var quoteNumber = 0
        var braceNumber = 0

        for character in name.characters {

            if braceNumber % 2 == 0 && braceNumber != 0 {
                if songName != "" {
                    quoteNumber = 0
                    self.previousSongs.append(PreviousSong(song: songName, artist: artistName, time: "TIME"))
                    songName = ""
                    artistName = ""
                }
            }

            if character == "{" || character == "}" {
                braceNumber++
            }

            if character == "\"" {
                quoteNumber++
            }

            if quoteNumber == 3 && character != "\""  {
                artistName += String(character)
            } else if quoteNumber == 7 && character != "\"" {
                songName += String(character)
            }

        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { self.getSongs() }
    }
    if self.previousSongs.count == 10 {
        task!.cancel()
    } else {
        task!.resume()
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    var song : PreviousSong
    song = previousSongs[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = song.song + " by " + song.artist
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Played at " + song.time

    return cell
}
```

The table will display the hard-coded array (`[PreviousSong(song: "NAME1", artist: "ARTIST1",`...), but it will not load the information from the array after I update it in the `getSongs()` function.

How can this be fixed, so that when I update the array with actual information in the `getSongs()` function, the cells will reload with the proper information? (I've already tried using the reloadData() method.)

Comment: Where's your code for `getSongs()`?

Comment: @Caleb Sorry, thought I had pasted everything in. I'm not good at writing code so you may find it appalling.

Comment: You are reloading data before the end of the completion handler. So only the hardcoded values are updated because the request has not completed yet when you ask to reload. You need to reload data at the end of the completion handler, when the values are updated.

Comment: @SwiftRabbit I'll be honest and say I don't know what you mean. I'm really pretty new to Swift so I don't understand.

Comment: @AlexB print something just before if error != nil {, compare it to the time the table appears. The print should execute after the tableview has appeared. If you don't notice anything, disable your internet. You will notice you still have the hardcoded values in your tableview. Should help you understand.

Comment: @SwiftRabbit Thank you, I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely sounds like your problem is in the `getSongs()` function. Would you mind providing your implementation?

Off the top of my head, it is probable that at least one of these is occurring: `previousSongs` is being set to nil or empty in `getSongs()`, your number of rows data source method is not returning the correct number (`previousSongs.count`).

Edit: After looking at your code, why would you not have the `getSongs()` function return an array and then use the `lazy` keyword on your array - then call your `getSongs()` function in the instantiation of the `previousSongs` array? That way, there would be no need to reload the table on `viewDidLoad()`. Pretty sure the whole thing would work a lot better.

Comment: I'm not very good at writing code, so you may find getSongs() to be rather abhorrent in terms of good coding. But I updated it.

Comment: Now that I'm looking at it,  I think my issue is that I'm appending to the array. Not overwriting the other values that I had hard-coded.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.getSongs() 
}
```

With:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
    self.tableView.reloadData() 
}
```

There's no reason that you should be calling `getSongs()` inside of `getSongs()`. You want to reload the table with `reloadData()` after the data has been processed. `reloadData()` in `viewDidLoad` does not execute after the data has been completely processed.

Comment: You're right about I shouldn't be calling it. The reason it was being called is that I was using a similar version of that function in another place where I needed to constantly call the `getSongs()` function.

Comment: Changing to your suggestion does not resolve the issue. Is it possible that my issue is that I am appending to the array?

Comment: @AlexB Put breakpoints and check your `previousSongs` array when the `tableView.reloadData()` is called in the `viewDidLoad()` and then check it again when it is called in the async. Appending to the array does not make a difference.

Comment: I will look into that. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexB I'm on mobile so I missed this. Your `previousSongs.count` is always 10. Do you want to clear the array each time? Only get 10 at a time? Right now, `task!.cancel()` is always called

Comment: @AlexB Also, "http://api.vicradio.org/songs/history?amount=10" seems to be limited to 10 so checking `previousSongs.count` seems unnecessary. You don't need your hardcoded data if you don't want it. I thought that was for debugging purposes.

Comment: the hardcoded data is necessary it seems, because when I try to run the application, it will crash and say the index is out of range in the cellForRowAtIndexPath. But you're right, checking is unnecessary.

Comment: @AlexB initialize `previousSongs` as `var previousSongs: [PreviousSong] = [PreviousSong]()` and you should be able to append

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution that I found!

Instead of appending to the array in `getSongs()`, use the `.insert` method. I think appending was adding the information I wanted to the end of the array. The data was being loaded correctly, but it wasn't the data I wanted.